# How to convert numeric quantity from European style to American style

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a sql query that is reading values like `1.000.000,000` (EU 1 million) from a table. I need the query to interpret these as `1,000,000.000` (American 1 million). How do I do this?

Comment: Just to be clear.  Are these values stored as a string?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti yes

Comment: The obvious solution is to not store them as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way

```
 SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('523,916','.',''), ',','.') AS NUMERIC(20,2));
```